# Bounded Compact Framework Multiline Textfield Not properly displaying newlines

Tags: c#, mobile, textbox, newline

I have two multiline text boxes, one bound, one not.

Both accept returns, both are multiline. I am able to add a new line with either Environment.Newline or with \r\n just fine and it displays how it should.

I have the 2nd box setup exactly the same, except it is bounded to a datasource (string property). The newlines appear as squares. If I do a replace on this text with searching for environment.newline or \r\n it finds the squares just fine so the datasource has the proper characters for displaying new lines.

I am able to copy the text property from the bound textbox directly into the unbound textbox and it will display fine in the unbound box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out that it was my data having odd characters surrounding the line breaks, the application it is pulled from isn't the greatest. When I'd copy the text of course those characters would be lost.